# Date displays in msgbox but not a variable to rename a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename a worksheet tab with last Saturday's date.  I can get the date to display properly using a Msgbox.

[image: MsgBox Image]

However when I try to use the same variable in the code, it throws a "Compile error: Expected: )".

[image: Error]

I know it is looking for a ) but I have literally tried putting in every position but still get the error.  Thank you for your consideration in helping solve this problem. Below is the entire subroutine.

```
Sub LastSaturdayIntExtMissTime()
'gets the past Saturday's date based on today.

    Dim iWeekday As Integer, LastSaturdayDate As Date, sfx As String

    iWeekday = Weekday(Now(), vbSaturday)
    LastSaturdayDate = Format(Now - (iWeekday - 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")

Select Case Right(Day(LastSaturdayDate), 1)

Case "1"
    sfx = """st"""
Case "2"
    sfx = """nd"""
Case "3"
    sfx = """rd"""
Case Else
    sfx = """th"""
End Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = (UCase(Format(Date, "mmm")) & " Data through " & Format(LastSaturdayDate, "mmm d" & sfx)   'this throws a compile error
MsgBox Format(LastSaturdayDate, "mmm d" & sfx)    'this works

End Sub
```

Comment: In cases like this jut use the Immediate window to debug the line. Try getting the value for each piece of the line. i.e. `Debug.Print (UCase(Format(Date, "mmm"))`; `Debug.Print " Data through "` and `Debug.Print Format(LastSaturdayDate, "mmm d" & sfx)`. At the first try you would have spotted the error...

Comment: `Oct 11st`??  `Oct 12nd`??  `Oct 13rd`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is erroring out:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = (UCase(Format(Date, "mmm")) & " Data through " & Format(LastSaturdayDate, "mmm d" & sfx)
```

Has and extra "(" in front of the equal sign. It should read:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = UCase(Format(Date, "mmm")) & " Data through  " & Format(LastSaturdayDate, "mmm d" & sfx)
```

Comment: Just saw that too.  It works great now.  thanks for the extra set of eyes.